# Как исправить код чтобы не выскакивало исключение "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: c++, рекурсия, stackoverflow

[Ссылка на код (godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/z/q6r4ae5Ks)

Подскажите что исправить в коде чтобы он корректно запускался? На данный момент сразу выскакивает исключение о переполнении стека. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема и как ее исправить.

**Результат:**

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7F259FB4E in Part_3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000C738003FF0).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF7F259FB4E in Part_3.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000C738003FF0).
```

**Исходный код:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

class Folder;

class Message
{
public:
    explicit Message(std::string message_text = "") : text(message_text) {}
    Message(Message& message) : text(message.text), folders(message.folders)
    {
        add_message_to_folders(*this);
    }
    ~Message()
    {
        remove_message_from_folders();
    }
    Message& operator=(Message& message)
    {
        remove_message_from_folders();
        text = message.text;
        folders = message.folders;
        add_message_to_folders(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    void add_folder(Folder& folder);
    void remove_folder(Folder& folder);
    std::string get_text()
    {
        return text;
    }
private:
    std::string text;
    std::set<Folder*> folders;
    void add_message_to_folders(Message& message);
    void remove_message_from_folders();
};

class Folder
{
public:
    Folder() = default;
    Folder(Folder& folder) : messages(folder.messages)
    {
        add_folder_to_messages(folder);
    }
    ~Folder()
    {
        remove_folder_from_messages();
    }
    Folder& operator=(Folder& folder)
    {
        remove_folder_from_messages();
        messages = folder.messages;
        add_folder_to_messages(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    void add_message(Message& message)
    {
        messages.insert(&message);
        message.add_folder(*this);
    }
    void remove_message(Message& message)
    {
        messages.erase(&message);
        message.remove_folder(*this);
    }
    void print_messages()
    {
        for (auto message : messages)
        {
            std::cout << message->get_text() << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    std::set<Message*> messages;
    void add_folder_to_messages(Folder& folder)
    {
        for (auto message : folder.messages)
        {
            message->add_folder(folder);
        }
    }
    void remove_folder_from_messages()
    {
        for (auto message : this->messages)
        {
            message->remove_folder(*this);
        }
    }
};

void Message::add_folder(Folder& folder)
{
    folders.insert(&folder);
    folder.add_message(*this);
}

void Message::remove_folder(Folder& folder)
{
    folders.erase(&folder);
    folder.remove_message(*this);
}

void Message::add_message_to_folders(Message& message)
{
    for (auto folder : message.folders)
    {
        folder->add_message(*this);
    }
}

void Message::remove_message_from_folders()
{
    for (auto folder : folders)
    {
        folder->remove_message(*this);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Folder folder;
    Message message_1("Message_1 Text");
    Message message_2("Message_2 Text");
    Message message_3("Message_3 Text");

    folder.add_message(message_1);
    folder.add_message(message_2);
    folder.add_message(message_3);

    folder.print_messages();

    folder.remove_message(message_3);

    folder.print_messages();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что, компилятор не пояснил?...

Начнем.

```
folder.add_message(message_1);
```

Что он вызывает?

```
void add_message(Message& message)
{
    ...
    message.add_folder(*this);  
}
```

Ага, а теперь посмотрим на нее...

```
void Message::add_folder(Folder& folder)
{
    ....
    folder.add_message(*this);
}
```

А что вызывается в этой функции? даже не надо ходить по коду — в ответе первый вызов таким и был. Итак, вечное "у попа была собака"... Более умными словами — бесконечная рекурсия.

Каковая не скажу уж, в каком количестве случаев из 100, но вряд ли меньше 50, является источником этого самого *stack overflow*...

Что до "что изменить в коде" — это вопрос совсем другого порядка. Кратко — убрать бесконечную рекурсию. Но для этого надо менять саму логику, а для этого надо знать, что *должна* делать программа, чтоб ее полностью переписать с той же функциональностью. Тут уж вам и <s>карты</s> клавиатуру в руки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Рекурсию убрал, удалив вызовы методов `add_folder` и `remove_folder` в методах `add_message/remove_message`. Но теперь получается что при добавлении сообщения в папку через вызов метода `add_message` у папки, в эту папку добавляется это сообщение, но само сообщение не знает в какой папке теперь находится, так как метод `add_folder` убран. Тоже самое с удалением.
Сейчас код работает только если добавлять и удалять сообщения через вызовы `add_folder/remove_folder` у самого сообщения, а если работать со стороны папки то собственно работает все некорректно

Comment: Видите ли, я намекал вам — "*для этого надо знать, что должна делать программа, чтоб ее полностью переписать с той же функциональностью*". Извините, но переписать программу даже при наличии описания, что она должна делать (а не только при наличии кода) - это большая работа, а уж просто по ее коду? Но как вариант - подумайте о том, не стоит ли при добавлении проверять - не добавлен ли ***уже*** данный объект, и в этом случае рекурсивный вызов не делать?